# How to get smooth corner radius on a non square Objective C UIImageView

Tags: objective-c, ios, uiimageview, image-manipulation, rounded-corners

I am trying to get a nice round corner on a UIImageView. I have found an implemented the following code, which works fine if the image is a square. The problem is that my imageView is a rectangular photo, sometimes portrait sometimes landscape. This code is clipping off the corners, but doesn't give a smooth curve when one side of the image is longer than the other. Any Ideas? Also is the float in setCornerRadius applied to the image as a percentage of the sides or just straight pixel count?

```
    // Get the Layer of any view
    CALayer * l = [imageView layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:100.0];
```

Here is the fix for all interested.

Okay after some playing with it I figured out I needed to resize the imageView to fit the image. I implemented the following method to set the frame size.

```
- (CGRect)getScaleForFrameFromImage:(UIImage *)image
{
    // get the bigger side of image to determine the shape then
    // get the percentage we need to scale to to trim imageViewFrame 
    // so it fits image and sits in the space dedicated in main view for the image
    float percentage;
    float newWidth;
    float newHeight;

    float w = image.size.width;
    float h = image.size.height;
    if (w > h) {
        // landscape
        percentage  = 280 / w;
        newWidth = w * percentage;
        newHeight = h * percentage;;
    }
    else {
        percentage  = 208 / h;
        newWidth = w * percentage;
        newHeight = h * percentage;
    }
    int xOrigin = 20 + (280 - newWidth) / 2;
    CGRect newFrame = CGRectMake(xOrigin, 160, newWidth, newHeight);
    return newFrame;
}
```

then in my viewWillAppear I did this

```
    // set the imageFrame size
    [imageView setFrame:[self getScaleForFrameFromImage:imageToDisplay]];

    // Use that image to put on the screen in imageView
    [imageView setImage:imageToDisplay];

    // Get the Layer of imageView
    CALayer * l = [imageView layer];
    [l setMasksToBounds:YES];
    [l setCornerRadius:10.0];
```

Comment: Can you post a screenshot? I thought the cornerRadius property worked fine on rectangular views. (It's a pixel count btw, not a percentage.)

Comment: Okay so I was in the process of making screenshots to post and I think I see the problem. When I took a portrait orient pic I got no round corners at all but the landscape was getting the funky warped corners. I think its because my UIImage view is sized to fill the largest area of my view I want the image to take up. It is also set for aspect fill in IB. I think the code is working fine, its just that my image rarely fills the whole view. So I guess what I should be looking @ is how to resize the view to its current image? Suggestions? I am shamefully still a newb ;~)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What i recommend  is to draw the imageView with the size of the image and then apply corner radius.

It would be something like this.

```
// get the size of the image.
CGSize *size = yourImage.size;

// use the size to set the uiimageview frame
UIImageView * imageView = [UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRecMake(0,0,size.widht,size.height)];
 [imageView setImage:yourImage];
//
CALayer * l = [imageView layer];
[l setMasksToBounds:YES];
[l setCornerRadius:100.0];
```

Comment: This is actually what I just realized. See comment above. The UIImageView is part of a view created to be a detail view in a Navigtion/TableView situation. I am currently setting the image for the view in viewWillAppear of the detailView. I need a way to resize the imageView on the fly, not during init. I'm going to see if i can figure that out and I'll get back to you. ;~)

Comment: Solved. Thanks for your help. See code in main post for the fix.